# return response to from php to ajax before script finishes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple AJAX request that to a PHP file. Once the PHP script reaches a certain point I would like for the response to be completed and sent back to the client. After that I still need the PHP script to run a function that takes up to 15 seconds. Currently the browser waits for the entire PHP script to finish before processing the response. I have tried to use `flush();` or `ob_flush();`, but it still waited for the PHP script to finish running before sending the response.

JQuery code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: "../phpFile.php",
            data: formdata,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(data.success){
                    window.location = "../public/dashboard.php";
                }
           }
});
```

PHP code:

```
if ($script_reached_this_point) {

    // ob_start();
    echo json_encode(['success' => 'Ticket added']);
    //flush();
    //  ob_end_flush();

    run_15_second_function();

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible.  Can you call two scripts, the 15 second one being fired after getting response from the first?

Comment: Thank, Yes I could have ajax make another request to the php script to run the function. I just thought it's inefficient as it's another request. I assumed I was missing a  basic solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you could start a separate process that can run in the background (and is set to not terminate when the main process does). The question is, why does that function run 15 seconds. thats very long ...

Comment: I am sending several different emails to different users.

Comment: StoneLight, if my solution works for you, please let me know! I remember how excited I was when it first worked for me.  @heybignick if the browser calls two scripts, wouldn't it still hang while waiting for the response from the long-lasting script?

Comment: BeetleJuice thanks I was able to use it. I did get all the header information as part of the response from worker.php (below) so I adjusted to code for it. Background work failed. Error: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 19:36:56 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
Content-Encoding: none
Connection: close
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved a similar problem by having 2 PHP scripts. Let's call them `receiver.php` and `worker.php`. The process is as follows:

1. AJAX calls `receiver.php`
2. `receiver.php` calls `worker.php` in a secondary connection, passes it the job instructions and waits for the first line of response.
3. As soon as the first line of response  arrives from `worker.php`, `receiver.php` closes that connection
4. `receiver.php` returns the response to AJAX immediately and exits.
5. `worker.php` continues work in the background

**receiver.php**

```
//data to be forwarded to worker.php
$postData = json_encode($_POST);

// headers for the connection to worker.php
$headers =  "POST /path/to/worker.php HTTP/1.1".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Host: localhost".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($postData).PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Encoding: none".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/json".PHP_EOL;

// create socket to the local webserver for calling background script
$socketToWorker = fsockopen("localhost", 80, $errno, $err_msg);
if(!$socketToWorker) die("fsockopen error #$errno: $err_msg");

// Make the request and send the POST data
fwrite($socketToWorker, $headers.PHP_EOL.$postData);    

//read until the 1st packet is returned, then stop. 8192 is arbitrary
//but needs to be greater than the expected response from worker.php
$data = fread($socketToWorker,8192);
fclose($socketToWorker);

//send response to browser (work still ongoing in background)
if($data==='OK') echo "Success";
else echo "Background work failed. Error: $data";
```

**worker.php**

```
//parse input from receiver.php
$postData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

//TODO: validate $postData. 

// If data is valid, set below to 'OK' to accept the job
$acceptJob = 'OK'; //replace with an error message to reject the job
ob_start(); //start the buffer
echo $acceptJob; //this is what receiver.php will see

//set headers for the response to receiver.php
header("Content-Encoding: none");
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length() );

// flush buffer. Will cause receiver.php to receive data and disconnect
ob_end_flush(); ob_flush(); flush();

if($acceptJob!=='OK') exit;

##################### START THE JOB HERE #####################
set_time_limit(60); //only needed if you expect job to last more than 30 secs
run_15_second_function();
```