# Javascript redirect doesn't work immediately on PHP process finish

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, apache

Hi I'm just wondering why is it that my javascript redirect doesn't work immediately after my php respond? Here's the scenario, 
1. I'm sending a post request to my php scripts. 
2. My php scripts then process this and return a string "ok" to identify that the process is done (but my script is doing a background process which takes too long). 
3. If the string is ok I will redirect the user to a confirmation page. But after returning the "ok" string my redirect don't take effect immediately it seems that its still waiting for the PHP process to finish. Below is my code

```
<?php 
    $success = $payment->do_payment();
    if (!$success) {
       throw new Exception("error on payment");
    }      

    set_time_limit(0);
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    header("Connection: close\r\n");
    header("Content-Encoding: utf-8\r\n");
    ob_start();

    echo "ok";  // This return to the frontend immediately

    $size = ob_get_length();
    header("Content-Length: {$size}", true);
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    // Below this line is a long php process that takes almost a minute
    $this->veryLongProcessRunningOnBackground();
```

and this is my jquery request

```
function payment_do_payment(token){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/payment',
        data:{
            mydata: "The data"
        },
        success: function(txt){
            if (txt == "ok"){
                console.log("done redirecting now");
                window.location.href = "/confirmation-page";
            }else{
                alert("Failed to process");
            }
        },
        type: 'POST'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use something like a socket connection to do this.

Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021073/return-response-to-from-php-to-ajax-before-script-finishes) will help.